# taken input from hard disk file in a matrix in Java

Tags: java, matrix, bufferedreader, jama

```
import Jama.Matrix;

public class T5 {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Matrix C=new Matrix(new double[][]{{1,0,0,},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}});
    Scanner x;
    try {
        x=new Scanner(new File("D://out.txt"));
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            double a1= x.nextDouble();
            Double b1=x.nextDouble();
            double c1=x.nextDouble();
            Matrix data1 = new Matrix(new double[][]{{a1, b1, c1}});
            double a = data1.get(i, 0);
            double b = data1.get(i, 1);
            double c = data1.get(i, 2);
            double[][] val = {{a}, {b}, {c}};
            Matrix A_new = new Matrix(val);
            Matrix newobser = C.times(A_new);
            newobser.print(9, 6);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

There is problem with this code. In this code there is a matrix `data1` which have three column and 1 rows which iterate over time. I have file in hard disk name `out.txt`.This file contain 100 rows and 3 columns.I try to take column 1 of out.txt in variable a1,column 2 of out.txt in variable b1,column 3 of out.txt in variable c1.Then input that a1,b1,c1 in Matrix data1.Here I use JAMA matrix which is a in build matrix package. `Get` and `print`, `times(use for matrix multiplication)` are  functions of JAMA matrix package. How could I proceed  to taken input from an outside file?My process doesn't work.

Comment: What does the content in your file look like?

Comment: `3.575008  -3.331063   2.346296`  
 `3.576784  -3.329287   2.351792`
 `3.578560  -3.327511   2.357288`
`3.580336  -3.325735   2.362784`
  `3.582112  -3.323959   2.368280`
  ................So on. It is arranged row and column wise. I am unable to show it here due to limited editing features.

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping the contents of the file into an object (representing each row) while reading the file line by line; and each record in a line tab or comma separated.

Then iterate over the list of all the objects holding the contents from the file and add them into the matrix.

Comment: How could I do this? Can you explain it by write down the code?